# LeetCode: my calender 2 C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge

https://leetcode.com/problems/my-calendar-ii/

> Implement a MyCalendarTwo class to store your events. A new event can
> be added if adding the event will not cause a triple booking.
>
> Your class will have one method, book(int start, int end). Formally,
> this represents a booking on the half open interval [start, end), the
> range of real numbers x such that start <= x < end.
>
> A triple booking happens when three events have some non-empty
> intersection (ie., there is some time that is common to all 3 events.)
>
> For each call to the method MyCalendar.book, return true if the event
> can be added to the calendar successfully without causing a triple
> booking. Otherwise, return false and do not add the event to the
> calendar.
> Your class will be called like this: `MyCalendar cal = new MyCalendar();` `MyCalendar.book(start, end)`

**Example 1:**

```
MyCalendar();
MyCalendar.book(10, 20); // returns true
MyCalendar.book(50, 60); // returns true 
MyCalendar.book(10, 40); // returns true
MyCalendar.book(5, 15); // returns false
MyCalendar.book(5, 10); // returns true
MyCalendar.book(25, 55); //returns true
```

> **Explanation:**
>
> - The first two events can be booked.  The third event can be double
>   booked.
> - The fourth event (5, 15) can't be booked, because it would result in a  triple booking.
> - The fifth event (5, 10) can be booked, as it does not use time 10 which is   already double booked.
> - The sixth event (25, 55) can be booked, as the time in [25, 40) will be  double booked with the third event; the time [40, 50) will be single booked,
>   and the time [50, 55) will be double booked with the second event.

> **Note:**
>
> The number of calls to MyCalendar.book per test case will be at most
> 1000. In calls to MyCalendar.book(start, end), start and end are integers in the range [0, 10^9].

Please review for style and performance

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ArrayQuestions
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyCalender2Test
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            MyCalendarTwo myCalendar = new MyCalendarTwo();
            Assert.IsTrue(myCalendar.Book(10, 20)); // returns true
            Assert.IsTrue(myCalendar.Book(50, 60)); // returns true
            Assert.IsTrue(myCalendar.Book(10, 40)); // returns true
            Assert.IsFalse(myCalendar.Book(5, 15)); // returns false
            Assert.IsTrue(myCalendar.Book(5, 10)); // returns true
            Assert.IsTrue(myCalendar.Book(25, 55)); // returns true
        }
    }

    public class MyCalendarTwo
    {
        private SortedDictionary<int, int> _dict;
        public MyCalendarTwo()
        {
            _dict = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// foreach start you add a pair of (start,1)
        /// foreach end you add a pair of (end,-1)
        /// the list is sorted we add and remove events.
        /// if we can more then 3 events added at the same time.
        /// we need to remove the event 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="start"></param>
        /// <param name="end"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool Book(int start, int end)
        {
            //   s1------e1
            // s-----e
            //      s---e
            // s------------e
            //      s---------e
            //s--e good
            //               s--e

            if(!_dict.TryGetValue(start, out var temp))
            {
                _dict.Add(start, temp + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                _dict[start]++;
            }

            if (!_dict.TryGetValue(end, out var temp1))
            {
                _dict.Add(end, temp1 - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                _dict[end]--;
            }
            
            int active = 0;
            foreach (var d in _dict.Values)
            {
                active += d;
                if (active >= 3)
                {
                    _dict[start]--;
                    _dict[end]++;
                    if (_dict[start] == 0)
                    {
                        _dict.Remove(start);
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Your MyCalendarTwo object will be instantiated and called as such:
     * MyCalendarTwo obj = new MyCalendarTwo();
     * bool param_1 = obj.Book(start,end);
     */
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after receiving answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too much to say on style, it all reads well to me. That said, there are a couple things I'd change.

You can get away with `_dict` as a field here but I think `_bookings` would be slightly nicer.

You can simplify the dictionary access too:

```
if(!_dict.TryGetValue(start, out var temp))
{
    _dict.Add(start, temp + 1);
}
else
{
    _dict[start]++;
}
```

I believe you could do:

```
var existingCount = _bookings.TryGetValue(start, out var count) ? count : 0;
_bookings[start] = existingCount + 1;
```

You could also filter your list when you iterate. Once you get to the end of the booking you're currently looking at, you don't need to keep going.

```
foreach (var d in _bookings.TakeWhile(kvp => kvp.Key < end).Select(kvp => kvp.Value))
```

It would be nice if you didn't have to add the start and end in to the dictionary but it does seem to be the simplest solution here. This can be a dangerous strategy because you have to ensure the entries you've added are always removed but I can't see any way your code can throw in the loop.

Comment: thanks you very much i appreciate the review

Answer (score 2):

Because the default value is returned for the value parameter in `_dict.TryGetValue()` if it returns false and the default value for `int` is `0` it should be save to do:

```
  _dict.TryGetValue(start, out int count);
  _dict[start] = count + 1;
  _dict.TryGetValue(end, out count);
  _dict[end] = count - 1;
```

---

As a micro optimization, you can reduce this:

```
      _dict[start]--;
      if (_dict[start] == 0)
      {
        _dict.Remove(start);
      }
```

to

```
      if (_dict[start] == 1)
        _dict.Remove(start);
      else
        _dict[start]--;
```

so that at least when you can remove start you do one operation less (two instead of three).

---

I wonder if you can remove `end` as well if it becomes `0` when incrementing it if `active >= 3`?

Comment: I had wondered about doing that with the dictionary too but I wasn't sure the value of the out parameter was specified when the method returns false. It is and you're quite right that it's default(TValue) so 0 for the int. I'm never sure about code that ignores a return value but I think it's fine here. Nice observation.

Comment: @Henrik Hansen yes i can remove end as well. i just missed it when uploaded the code. i fixed it later.